# Angular Material not applying styles

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've followed the guide on how to install angular material.
First I added it via the cli

> ng add @angular/material

In the app.module.ts I've added the following additional lines:

```
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker'; 
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';



imports: [
    [...],
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule 
  ],
  providers: [MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule],
```

and in my HTML file I tried to create a datetimepicker

```
<mat-form-field color="accent" appearance="fill">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Unfortunately, the styling doesn't work at all. It looks like this:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

---

edit:
After adding the imports for MatFormFieldModule and MatInputModule it now looks like this which is still different from the tutorial:

[image]

Comment: hi mate, could u give any response if that solved ur problem? regards

Comment: did u stop ng serve and reserved :)

Comment: yes, the field does look different than before but not like the template. I imported the pink & blue-grey template so shouldn't all be dark?

Comment: I have prepared a stackblitz for u --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y739ny the background should be greyish. And u should see the suffix calendar icon.

Comment: Yeah that's what I would expect :)

Comment: Usually ng add does everything for u. DId u finish the console questions after using ng add?

Comment: If I change the <link> in index.html to `<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css" rel="stylesheet">` I get the same issue that I have in my project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218691/discussion-between-sagat-and-xeraphim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly show the right styles you will also need to import the MatFormFieldModule and the MatInputModule to your app.module.ts file like so:

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker'; 
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';    

imports: [
    [...],
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
providers: [MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule]
```

You can see that you need them by analyzing the html which consists of `<mat-form-field></mat-form-field>` and the `<input>` tag has a matInput directive on it.

regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, it still doesn't look as expected :( I will update the original post